# Windows 11 taskbar greyed out and is not usable when logging in with ad domain user

Tags: windows-11, windows-server, windows-domain

Today I've tried to setup an AD domain in my home environment and am unsure of what's happening. I've set up folder redirection, roaming profiles and connected a "base folder" for the user profile.

I can login just fine, but the system is unusable. All subfolders are working as expected, but the taskbar is greyed out, no icons showing except for the small icons for "background apps running".
I cannot rightclick anything - does nothing - and cannot open the explorer for example and not the trash bin.

The only way to run programs is by using the execute functionality built into task manager - which I can access via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>.

Event viewer does show a few application errors after login for StartMenuExpercienceHost.exe, SearchHost.exe and SystemSettings.exe. I am however lost to why this might occur.

Logging in with a local, non-domain user works just fine.

I‘ve set up a fresh domain using Windows Server 2022 including a DNS server. The client gets the DNS server as primary and my router as secondary.

I‘ve created domain users to login with and joined the AD domain using a windows 11 client. I‘ve not yet added any GPO‘s except for folder redirection so everything is default regarding that.
The user accounts are standard domain users as well and have only been assigned a mapped folder to drive letter `Z:` and a Roaming profile.

Desktop
[image: desktop]

Event viewer
[image: event viewer]

Comment: Turn off Roaming Profiles.  That is a very old concept. Best not to use them.

Comment: @harrymc you mean the others in event viewer? I can add these tomorrow.

Comment: @John well it should still work. At work I am in a Server 2016 environment with Windows 11 clients and enabled roaming profiles - it works just fine. I also like to save my profile on the server instead of the client. What alternative would you suggest?

Comment: Everything I have read able Roaming Profiles is that they are hit and miss. I have not seen them in active use since 1999-2000.

Comment: also like to save my profile on the server instead of the client. .... Best done on the client in my experience with servers.

Comment: @John I guess you sugesst to use folder redirection instead, right? How does this behave when upgrading the client OS? Roaming profiles create different versions in the SMB-path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since I've finally figured things out.

Due to previous problems with the folder permissions on the server something seems to have been messed up with the `%appdata%/Local/Packages` folder, even though only roaming was saved on the server.

The deletion of the profile with `sysdm.cpl > Advanced > User Profiles > Settings` has solved the issues after another login.